# Fibonacci extension in c++ segfaulting

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, fibonacci

I'm trying to add the extension to the Fibonacci numbers to take into account negative indexes.
The extension is Fib(-n) = (-n)^(n+1) * Fib(n)
I have attempted to implement this in c++ but I'm running into a problem and I'm not sure how to get around it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


int fib(int n) {
    if ( n < 0 ){ 
        return ( pow(-1,-n+1 ) * fib(-n) );
    }else if (n == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }
}


int main(void){
    std::cout << "fib("<< -2<<") = " << fib(-2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me a segfault, any idea why this is?

EDIT:
I figured out what the problem is. Forgot a base case and this caused an infinite recursion, which in turn caused a segfault.

Comment: use `<cmath>` header in `c++`

Comment: @phadej, I should be doing this for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that when u call `fib(-2)` it calls `fib(2)`

`fib(2)` calls `fib(1)` and `fib(0)`

`fib(1)` calls `fib(0)` and `fib(-1)`

`fib(-1)` calls `fib(1)` and this is never-ending loop

Answer (score 1):

This will cause infinite recursion. You need two terminating cases, not one.

Take for example `fib(1)`. This will call `fib(0)` and `fib(-1)`. `fib(0)` will terminate, but `fib(-1)` will call `fib(1), which will then again call`fib(-1)` ad infinitum.

Solution: Terminate the recursion if `n==0` or `n==1`.

Sidenote: `fib(0)` is usually defined as 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

Oops I made a stupid mistake forgetting the n== -1 base case. It should be:

```
int fib(int n) {
    if( n == -1){
        return 1;
    }else if ( n < 0 ){ 
        return ( pow(-1,-n+1 ) * fib(-n) );
    }else if (n == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }
}
```

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: with this definition, fib(1) will be fib(0)+fib(-1) = 2. Normally fib(1) is 1. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number. In case you want the different behavior, I would not call it fib or fibonacci since reading this code (or its output) would surprise the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
According to your extension, shouldn't this be:
int fib(int n) { 
    if ( n < 0 ){  
        return ( pow(-1,n+1 ) * fib(n) ); // <<<
    }else if (n == 0){ 
        return 1; 
    }else{ 
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
    } 
}
```